CMake unable to 'find' Foundation framework on macOS 15.1.1 (24B91)
When I try a build, this is the error I see:
-- Adding CPU backend variant ggml-cpu:  
CMake Error at ggml/src/ggml-metal/CMakeLists.txt:1 (find_library):
  Could not find FOUNDATION_LIBRARY using the following names: Foundation

due to
find_library(FOUNDATION_LIBRARY Foundation REQUIRED)

failing.
My understanding is that the Foundation library comes with default in macOS but I'm not an expert developing on that OS. Also, this is what I see:
 ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/          
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   27 14 Nov 23:59 Foundation -> Versions/Current/Foundation
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   26 14 Nov 23:59 Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  128 14 Nov 23:59 Versions
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   28 14 Nov 23:59 XPCServices -> Versions/Current/XPCServices

So, why is CMake of my build not pulling the library correctly?

This question is similar to: Why I cannot link the Mac framework file with CMake?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@RichardBarber: The answer to the question you reference explicitly tells, that find_library is able to find the framework, and its result is suitable for link. But given question is about find_library not finding a framework at all.

I usually just have -framework Foundation in my CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS without any requirements that it search for the stub file, which I believe Apple changed up a number of years ago.
